# How to match all whitespace in VBA

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I am having a similar issue [as this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501586/vba-6-regex-not-recognizing-complicated-string). `\s` is not matching all white spaces in VBA.

But I want to catch [all kinds of whitespace - spaces, tabs, newlines, thin space, hair space etc.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Definition_and_ambiguity) and not only one of them.

Is there another possibility than hard coding every unicode value like the following?

```
With regEx
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "(\s|\u2009|\u2008|.............)"
End With
```

> [How do I isolate a space using RegExp in VBA (\s vs. \p{Zs})?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28617616/how-do-i-isolate-a-space-using-regexp-in-vba-s-vs-pzs) wants to isolate spaces - I want readable and reliable way to match any whitespace without needing to list the unicode values for them as proposed by the one who closed the question.

Comment: Depending on what you need to do with them. If you need to **remove any extra leading or trailing whitespaces**, instead of checking them through regex, why not just [`Trim()`](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/trim.php) them instead?

Comment: @Rawrplus - I don't think Trim works on ChrW(8203).

Comment: No it doesn't, though it is a place to start. Might want to trim it initially, and then remove any extra unwanted characters such as hairspace with [`REPLACE()`](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/replace_vba.php) I am however too lazy to re-create a working replace condition / regexp for all the unwanted characters you provided above. *sorry...*

Answer (score 2):

There is no perfect alternative, therefore I suggest to use exact values/codes.

You should be safe with this regex pattern:

```
[\s\n\r\t \xA0\u1680\u180E\u2000-\u200B\u202F\u205F\u3000\uFEFF]+
```